# Python replace backward (\) with forward (/)

Tags: python

I am trying to replace `\` with `/`. However, I'm having no success.
Following is the snapshot of the scenario that I am trying to achieve

```
string = "//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservo\171002"        
print string.replace("\\","/")
```

**Output:**

```
//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservoy002
```

**Desired output:**

```
//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservo/171002
```

Comment: `\171` is an escape sequence, if used in a string literal Python parses that as an octal number for a byte value. `int('171', 8)` is 121, or 0x79 in hexadecimal, which is the ASCII character `y`. Your string *value* **has no backslashes in it**, so there is nothing to replace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape "\" with an extra "\".

```
>>> string = "//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservo\\171002"
>>> string
'//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservo\\171002'  
>>> print string.replace("\\","/")
//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservo/171002
```

Comment: Hi Raju, I have this string already in the table. Is there any solution that works on without adding extra slash in the original string

Comment: What do you mean by table?@user55641 If you already have the text in a variable that means it is already escaped with an extra "\". So just print string.replace("\\","/")  should work fine.

Comment: I am reading the csv file using pandas and this string is just an example of the row in the table.

Comment: @user55641: Then **show that pandas dataframe**, because the data you gave us in the question does **not** have a backslash in the string.

Comment: @user55641: in other words: if your question is based on an incorrect example, it is up to you to provide a correct example.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = r"//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservo\171002"
print string.replace("\\","/")
```

output

```
//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservo/171002
```

Answer (score 0):

You have errors both in *replace* function and in string definition.

- In your string definition `\171` gives char with octal value of 171 – *y*
- In you replace function, backslash escapes quote.

You should escape backslashes

```
string = "//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservo\\171002"
string.replace("\\","/")
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use ".replace" in python or if you want you can use regex :

```
import re
string = r"//SQL-SERVER/Lacie/City of X/Linservo\171002"

pattern=r'[\\]'

replaced_string=re.sub(pattern,"/",string)

print(replaced_string)
```

Since your original question shows : `"X/Linservo\171002"`  here `\171` referring to character encoding so it's replacing `\171` to `"y"`. you can try this in python interpreter :

```
In[2]: print("\171")

y
```